# Request Error Twitter-API Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm wondering how to limit the number of followers returned via the twitter api, or if there's a better way of returning the twitter followers of a user.

We've been challenged to create a twitter manager, and I've done most of the stuff, but I keep getting a request error when someone has a large amount of followers, as we're supposed to get the users from the twitter api and store them in a database, and the page usually times out or gives a twitter get error too many requests and locks me out for an hour. It's very hard to develop when this keeps happening, I was just wondering if there's a better way to do it?

Here is my code for the dashboard which is where the user details are returned and saved, and also where the followers are returned and save:

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

    helper_method :logged_in?

    def new
        @just_updated = ""
        Twitter.configure do |config|
            # Test Account
            config.consumer_key = "none-of-your-business"
            config.consumer_secret = "none-of-your-business"
            config.oauth_token = "none-of-your-business"
            config.oauth_token_secret = "none-of-your-business"
        end

        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        if @user.twitter_username.present? && @user.twitter_details_present == false
            @twitter_user = Twitter.user(@user.twitter_username)
            @user.no_of_followers = @twitter_user[:followers_count]
            @user.profile_picture_url = @twitter_user[:profile_image_url]
            @user.following = @twitter_user[:friends_count]
            @user.twitter_nationality = @twitter_user[:location]
            @user.no_of_tweets = @twitter_user[:statuses_count]

            @user.twitter_details_present = true
            @user.updated_at = Time.now
            if @user.save
                @just_updated = "We have just updated your follower details"
            else
                @just_updated = "There was a problem with your save1"
            end
        end
        if (Time.now - @user.updated_at) < 10.minute && (@user.updated_at - @user.created_at) > 1.hour
            Follower.where("owner = #{@user.id}").destroy_all
        end
        if @user.twitter_username.present?
            if (@followers = Follower.where("owner = #{@user.id}")).count > 0
                i = Follower.first.id
                @followers.each do |follower|
                    if (Time.now - Follower.where("owner = #{@user.id}").first.updated_at) > 1.hour
                        if (follower_to_save = Follower.where(follower_id: follower[:id])).present?
                            follower_to_save[0].follower_username = follower[:screen_name].to_s
                            follower_to_save[0].owner = @user.id
                            follower_to_save[0].follower_nationality = follower[:location]
                            follower_to_save[0].no_of_followers = follower[:followers_count]
                            follower_to_save[0].following= follower[:friends_count]
                            follower_to_save[0].no_of_tweets = follower[:statuses_count]
                            follower_to_save[0].profile_picture_url = follower[:profile_image_url]
                            follower_to_save[0].updated_at = Time.now
                            if follower_to_save[0].save
                                @just_updated = "We have just updated your follower details"
                            else
                                @just_updated = "There was a problem with your save1"
                                break;
                            end
                        else
                            follower_to_save = Follower.new
                            follower_to_save.follower_id = follower[:id]
                            follower_to_save.owner = @user.id
                            follower_to_save.follower_username = follower[:screen_name]
                            follower_to_save.follower_nationality = follower[:location]
                            follower_to_save.no_of_followers = follower[:followers_count]
                            follower_to_save.following= follower[:friends_count]
                            follower_to_save.no_of_tweets = follower[:statuses_count]
                            follower_to_save.profile_picture_url = follower[:profile_image_url]
                            follower_to_save.updated_at = Time.now
                            if follower_to_save.save
                                @just_updated = "We have just updated your follower details"
                            else
                                @just_updated = "There was a problem with your save2"
                                break;
                            end
                        end
                    else
                        next
                    end
                    i=i+1
                    #sleep(1)
                end
            else
                @followers = Twitter.followers(@user.twitter_username)
                @followers.each do |follower|
                    follower_to_save = Follower.new
                    follower_to_save.follower_id = follower[:id]
                    follower_to_save.owner = @user.id
                    follower_to_save.follower_username = follower[:screen_name]
                    follower_to_save.follower_nationality = follower[:location]
                    follower_to_save.no_of_followers = follower[:followers_count]
                    follower_to_save.following= follower[:friends_count]
                    follower_to_save.no_of_tweets = follower[:statuses_count]
                    follower_to_save.profile_picture_url = follower[:profile_image_url]
                    follower_to_save.updated_at = Time.now
                    if follower_to_save.save
                        @just_updated = "We have just compiled your followers"
                    else
                        @just_updated = "There was a problem with your save3"
                        break;
                    end
                    #sleep(1)
                end
            end
        else
            @no_twitter_username = "Please go into settings and add your twitter username to start."
        end
        @followers = Follower.all.where("owner = #{@user.id}")
        @follower_count = @followers.count

    end
    def logged_in?
        if session[:user_id].present?
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

end
```

The code is pretty inefficient right now, but I'm just trying to get it working.

Comment: What twitter gem are you using? This one (https://github.com/sferik/twitter) has pretty clear documentation on how you can limit the number of followers returned: http://sferik.github.io/twitter/
Checkout the section about Twitter::Cursors. You can do: twitter_client.friends.take(20) to get the 20 most recent followers.

Comment: The issue I'm having with this though is that I'm using this with multiple twitter users. So I can't use the friends method, as it does not exist in the Twitter::User method. This is the issue I'm having, as you should be able to see in my code.

Comment: Yea I just didn't want to read that horrific mess, sorry. Gleaming from the docs it seems like what you need can't be accomplished with the Twitter::User class. It only says you can limit returned followers using a Twitter::Cursor

Comment: Wow, blunt much? No need for that. It can be done, because sites do it, my question was how can I use the twitter API to do it, even if it's not with this gem.

Comment: Yea my bad, I left that comment before coffee :P The Twitter REST API docs state that the followers/list endpoint returns a cursored list of  followers: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list - it will return a next_cursor parameter allowing you to append that to the next request to get the next page of followers. The REST API can be simple enough to implement with curl, or in Ruby with the NET::HTTP library. Or, as I prefer, with HTTParty!

Comment: Looks like a good gem HTTParty :P I'm not entirely sure how to base it solely with HTTP that's why I used the Twitter gem, I've already written quite a lot of stuff with it, would it be easy enough to implement with my current structure? I'm pretty new to using external applications in Rails.

Comment: Then just stick with the gem you're using. Have you tried playing around with it the Twitter::Cursor class? http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter#Cursors

Comment: I haven't yet no, but my issue is that the cursor can't be used alongside the User method in the Twitter class, so the problem is that I can't really use the cursor, well not that I'm aware of, maybe I'm overlooking something, but I couldn't see a method within User that looked like cursor. The problem with using Twitter::Cursor is that the cursor applies to the user that's bound to the apps followers and not the user that's using the app.